# Multiple configuration build in yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

I have to build u-boot for multiple configurations, 6 different configurations to be precise. I need to create multiple binaries for all 6 configurations.

I have achieved by creating multiple machine for each configuration and I am able to build all the configurations. Each configuration add different patch that's why we need theses may configurations. But issue I am facing is that we need single machine type and how to I build multiple configurations from single machine.

```
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_mx6 = "mx6"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_imx6-abc = "imx6-abc"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_imx6-xyz = "imx6-xyz"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_abc-uboot-imx = "abc-uboot-imx"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_abc-uboot-imx-secure = "abc-uboot-imx-secure"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_abc-uboot-secure = "abc-uboot-secure"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_abc-encryption = "abc-encryption"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_abc-provisioning = "abc-provisioning"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_abc-factory-test = "abc-factory-test"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_xyz-factory-test = "xyz-factory-test"
```

Above machines build the separate configurations images but I need to achieve the same with single machine only.

```
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_mx6 = "mx6"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_imx6-abc = "imx6-abc"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_imx6-xyz = "imx6-xyz"
```

With only one machine type, how i should build multiple configuration. Please comment!

Comment: If you can show what the difference between the configurations is, we might be able to help you.

Comment: All 6 configuration files are adding different configuration such as in secure its using internal CAAM enable configuration, similarly others have different configurations. But all configuration are going to be used in in single target board. So it needs to be a single machine name.

Comment: You can create multiple machines with a common `SOC_FAMILY` or `MACHINEOVERRIDES` so you can factorize some recipes? You can also define a complete custom variable that you set in local.conf that will manage your multiple configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe you are looking for `UBOOT_CONFIG`.

You could do the following in your single machine configuration:

```
UBOOT_CONFIG = "abc def xyz"
UBOOT_CONFIG[abc] = "ubootconfig1_defconfig"
UBOOT_CONFIG[def] = "ubootconfig2_defconfig"
UBOOT_CONFIG[xyz] = "ubootconfig3_defconfig"
```

See: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-UBOOT_CONFIG

Comment: Will it create multiple directory for each configurations to store the respective images?

Comment: It will put the resulting U-Boot images in tmp/deploy/images/. They will not be in separate directories by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and support!! I know i am late to respond, apology!!